# MySqldump success or failure test

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysqldump to take the backup of my mysql database and have put it under a cron job . I want to test its success or failure and want it to echo the Success or Failure Message in the cron job email but failing ? Please help me out...

What command to pass ? I did this but failed :

In my php backup script I included:

```
$testvar = '
        if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] then
    echo "Success"
    else
    echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information"
    fi
        ';

exec($testvar);
```

My server says : Unexpected End of File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you had other methods preceding this that also make use of `exec`... and thus your logic is flawed.  Every time you execute a command using `exec`, your working in a fresh blank environment, and the previous session's data is no longer available;  and as such `$?` will not have the value you're looking for.  You need to stop trying to write bash scripts inside of PHP.

For example, in one of your comments you mentioned the following:

> i did this : $Backup = "mysqldump .........."; exec($Backup); $testvar
>   ='.............'; exec($testvar); $createzip ='..........'; exec($createzip);

When instead of trying to execute bash commands as a variable... you should be executing only the necessary commands outside of PHP.

instead of something like

```
$testvar = '
    /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBuser -pDBpassword database >database.sql 2>database.err
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "Success"
    else
    echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information"
    fi
        ';

$MysqlDumpMsg=exec($testvar);
echo $MysqlDumpMsg;
```

You should be doing something more like this:

```
exec("mysqldump .......... 2>database.err",$MysqlDumpMsg,$MysqlDumpCode);
if ($MysqlDumpCode = 0) {
  echo "Success";
} else {
  echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information";
}
```

or whatever else you need.  If you have some zip'ing command in there someplace... then do it as several steps...

```
exec("mysqldump .......... >database.sql 2>database.err",$MysqlDumpMsg,$MysqlDumpCode);
if ($MysqlDumpCode = 0) {
  echo "Successfully dumped database.";
  exec("gzip database.sql", $ZipMsg, $ZipReturnCode)
  if ($ZipReturnCode = 0) {
    echo "Successfully zip'd database!";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to compress the database."
  }
} else {
  echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information";
}
```

Comment: ... customize as needed.

Comment: sir, shall I put the script--'mysqldump......>abc.sql'     in a mybackupscript.sh file and run it from my php script file. as the content is a bash script content , and am using EXEC for running it.

Comment: As I said... customize it as needed.  My point being... don't try & write bash scripts inside of PHP... Let PHP do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your "if" statement...

```
$testvar = '
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Success"
    else
      echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information"
    fi
    ';

exec($testvar);
```

semi-colons are important :D

Comment: Sir, it still says : sh:
: command not found
sh: -c: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: In you environment... do you have a sym-link to your shell in /bin called "sh" ... i.e. /bin/sh -> /bin/bash (or dash/ash/csh/whatever shell)

Comment: sir, am just working through cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Several things going on here

- You don't appear to be running a mysqldump command.
- `$?` is the exit status of the last command, you don't have a command before the test so it's probably not valid.
- The output from the shell script will be returned to the exec command. You are ignoring it.
- you are as @TheCompWiz points out missing an important `;`

Try something like this

```
$testvar = '
    /usr/bin/mysqldump -u DBuser -pDBpassword database >database.sql 2>database.err
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
    then
        /usr/bin/zip database.zip database.sql >/dev/null 2>>database.err
        if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
        then
             echo "Succcess"
        else
             echo "Mysqldump succeeded but zip failed see database.err for details"
        fi
    else
    echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information"
    fi
        ';

$MysqlDumpMsg=exec($testvar);
echo $MysqlDumpMsg;
```

This captures the output from the shell script and outputs it so that the cron job should mail it to you.

Comment: sir , i did this :  $Backup = "mysqldump ..........";                           exec($Backup);                                                              $testvar ='.............';                                   exec($testvar);                                   $createzip ='..........';    exec($createzip);

Comment: Rather than trying to get the return code on a 2nd command call... (which is what you're doing) ... try using the `exec` command properly... i.e. `exec($Backup,outputText,returnCode);`

Comment: Sir,  I am having a create zip command after testing the shell variable , will it effect the output?

Comment: Every time you exec(...) something you are creating a new shell so the `$?` in your second exec is invalid.

Comment: sqlchild, you're working too hard.  the exec statement spawns a new shell and executes the statement.  Don't try & make php run bash commands... make php execute single commands and capture the output in a variable and work with the return code... or write a bash script to do everything, and have php call that single bash script.

Comment: can you please help me out sir, i just want to do two steps ; Create a Backup , Create that Backup's Zip  , and check whether the Backup was Successful or NOT ?....Now please can you guide me

Comment: @TheCompWiz -can you please help me out sir, i just want to do two steps ; Create a Backup , Create that Backup's Zip , and check whether the Backup was Successful or NOT ?....Now please can you guide me

Comment: Upadated my answer which should work and give you some hints.